# requestWindowFeature() in External Class by Passing Activity Context

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make most of the utility functions abstract, so I decided to separate them in a new class called Utils.java (inside the Android app package).

However, I am having hard time passing the activity context to this helper class and run some system stuff in its (the helper class' methods).

I have this scenario in the main activity's onCreate:

```
Utils u = new Utils(this);
u.makeFullscreen();
```

Utils.java:

```
package mypackagenamehere;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Utils{
    Context context;

    // Constructor  
    public Utils(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public void makeFullscreen(){
        context.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        context.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

}
```

The issue is with the contents of the makeFullscreen() method.

Comment: make sure you have called `makeFullscreen` before `setContentView` as It is a must requirement. becuae you are calling `requestWindowFeature` in that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Utils u = new Utils(YourActivityName.this);
```

and better to do like this

```
public stactic void makeFullscreen(Context context){
        context.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        context.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

then call directly

```
Utils.makeFullscreen(YourActivityName.this);
```

Comment: But the thing is that I plan on including other methods beside makeFullscreen. I need to be able to just set the Activity context once, preferably in the constructor, and then invoke the same instance of the Utils class for each method that I need to run without having to pass the context to each.

Comment: Yes and I still can not run the application in Eclipse due to an error in this method.